# Is there any rules engine(cheap or free) known to work in android

Tags: android, android-ndk

We are looking for a rules engine(similar to CLIPS,JESS) which works on android. It should not require us to do any source code modification.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout HeaRTDroid: https://bitbucket.org/sbobek/heartdroid/wiki/Home

It is a rule engine designed for Android.
It supports integration with android apps via callbacks based on Java reflection and easy tonise uncertainty handling mechanism

Answer (score 0):

*No first-hand experience, but maybe this helps...*

Should be possible with [CLIPS](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/WhatIsCLIPS.html):

> CLIPS is written in C for portability and speed and has been installed on many different operating systems without code changes. [...] CLIPS can be ported to any system which has an ANSI compliant C or C++ compiler.

JESS is written in Java, [can already be embedded into applications](http://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/71/embedding.html) and doesn't seem to mention any additional dependencies. So I'd expect that to work without modification as well.

Comment: In my opinion, Jess might be a decent Java implementation of Clips but its Java integration is an awkward afterthought.  Using objects as facts (shadow facts), calling methods and even dealing with booleans are all pretty poor compared to more progressive rule engines like Drools for example.  Unfortunately, I don't believe it runs on Android either.

Answer (score 0):

There's a response on the Jess mailing list related to this topic: http://www.mail-archive.com/jess-users@sandia.gov/msg11715.html. According to the response, it's not possible to run an unmodified version of Jess on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Check Andrmate the high performance rule engine for Android.